# Bourne shell: how to redirect to multiple-digit fd?

Tags: sh, output-redirect

In a C program I have a file descriptor (actual example: 14, but of course the program doesn't know this in advance) open for writing.  I wish to call `system(3)` to run something and send its standard output to this file descriptor.  Of course, this calls `/bin/sh`, which is the Bourne shell, which doesn't recognize constructs of the form `1>&14`.  Is there an alternative syntax (perhaps using braces or something) which I can use to let the Bourne shell see the 14 and use it?  I could of course do one of these:

1. Do a `fork`/`exec` combo instead of `system(3)` and redirect by hand.
2. Redirect the output to a file and then copy the data therefrom to file descriptor 14.
3. Since I have root, have `/bin/sh` point to Bash.

The most elegant way would be to discover a syntax by which the Bourne shell will accept a multiple-digit file descriptor number.  Is there such?

Comment: I know for certain that newer version of `ksh93` support multi-digit file descriptors. I pretty sure you reference them as `1>{14}` etc. So seems likely that `zsh` and `bash` also have this feature. As you asked ".. perhaps using braces", maybe you should try it? Bourne Shell, definitely not in the standard versions associated with original unix systems but who know what you'll find in more modern versions associated with Linux. (is there are real Bourne Shell for Linux?) . Good luck.

Comment: For bourne shell (which I use with FreeBSD; I never encountered it with Linux), `1>&{14}` fails with an error message, and `1>{14}` fails silently. bash uses `1>&14`.  While on Linux (from which I'm migrating), I used bash as my `/bin/sh`.  Looks like on FreeBSD I'll do the same.  That's the easiest way to make my legacy code work smoothly.

Comment: Good stuff. Thanks for the feedback/info. Sounds like you've decided on a solution, glad you can move forward. Good luck to all!

Comment: ... except I've just discovered that bash lacks something the bourne shell has: the `setvar` command. This breaks essential shell scripts which are run when booting FreeBSD. So it's back to the drawing board. Maybe the best solution is to create a C function called bash_system, which is just like `system(3)` except it calls bash, not `/bin/sh`.

Answer (score 1):

Consider my favorite rules about optimization: (1) Do not optimize. (2) For experts: do not optimize yet.

The situation arising in the question will (for me) arise in code which will be executed at most 100 times a day.  So this will suffice:

```
sprintf(big_string,
        "bash -c \"somethingsomething 1>&%d\"",
        the_fd
       );
```